# Convert codeigniter query to sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i am little confused in wririting  SQL query for joining muthiple tables.
I have perfectly write that query in codeigniter as folows

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('subscription_payment'); 
$this->db->join('user', 'user.user_id = subscription_payment.user_id');
$this->db->join('subscription', 'subscription.subscription_id = 
subscription_payment.subscription_id');
$this->db->where('subscription_payment.subscription_payment_id',$sid);
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$result= $query->result_array();
```

Help me to convert this to SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription_payment
JOIN user ON user.user_id = subscription_payment.user_id
JOIN subscription ON subscription.subscription_id = subscription_payment.subscription_id
WHERE subscription_payment.subscription_payment_id = $sid 
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

will produce

```
select * from some_table...
```

And this is it. Next time you can convert any query you want with easy.

Comment: as a note : if you can't produce this last queries, try to check if the database `save_queries` [config](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/database.php#L59) is set to `true` (it's `true` by default)

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from subscription_payment 
join user
on user.user_id = subscription_payment.user_id
join subscription
on subscription.subscription_id =  subscription_payment.subscription_id
where subscription_payment.subscription_payment_id = $sid
```